# Chancing the color of a random chosen object from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, colors

I am making a top view bird game, and trying to change the color of only one of the chosen element from the array. I am pretty new to JavaScript and general. I think I did the choosing part correct, but whatever I do, couldn't manage to change the color. I am only stuck with changing the color part, so didn't include the rest of the code. Cheers!

```
//Drawing the basic bird shape
function drawBird(ctx, bird) {
const angle = Math.atan2(bird.dy, bird.dx);
ctx.translate(bird.x, bird.y);
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.translate(-bird.x, -bird.y);
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(bird.x, bird.y);
ctx.lineTo(bird.x - 30, bird.y + 10);
ctx.lineTo(bird.x - 30, bird.y - 10);
ctx.lineTo(bird.x, bird.y);
ctx.fill();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);}

//Choosing one of the elements of the array
const randomElement = birds[Math.floor(Math.random() * birds.length)];

//Here suppose to be changing the color
```

Comment: `//Here suppose to be changing the color` where is the code you have tried in order to change the color of the bird?

Comment: I tried whatever I could find online but none had worked, but If you want one, I had hopes for this one :D `function changeBirdColor(color) { document.body.style.fill = color;}`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a color parameter to your drawBird function and run it again after randomly choosing a bird

```
//Drawing the basic bird shape
function drawBird(ctx, bird, color) {
const angle = Math.atan2(bird.dy, bird.dx);
ctx.translate(bird.x, bird.y);
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.translate(-bird.x, -bird.y);
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(bird.x, bird.y);
ctx.lineTo(bird.x - 30, bird.y + 10);
ctx.lineTo(bird.x - 30, bird.y - 10);
ctx.lineTo(bird.x, bird.y);
ctx.fill();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

//Choosing one of the elements of the array
const randomElement = birds[Math.floor(Math.random() * birds.length)];

//Here suppose to be changing the color

drawBird(ctx, randomElement, "purple");
```

Comment: Then how do I decide the color for the rest of the birds ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, why you randomly select a bird? 
If you just want to draw all the birds you can give each bird a color property and do something like 

birds.forEach(bird => drawBird(ctx, bird))

Comment: To be exact, I am creating any number of birds which can be selected by user. Then, If the user wants, they can select one randomly and by making it a different color they can follow it around easily